# Adding a line break after a full uppercase title in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, object

I am currently working on a project where the API spits a description that is formatted like this:

> THIS IS A TITLE This is a paragraph. This is another paragraph.

And the outcome I am trying to get is

> THIS IS A TITLE
>
> This is a paragraph
>
> This is another paragraph

I have been playing with some regular expressions but struggling to get the desired result, my current attempt is adding a line break at the end of each Uppercase letter/word.

```
var myString = "THIS IS A TITLE This is a paragraph of random text. This is another paragraph of random text.";
var myStringFormatted = myString.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, ",$1").replace(/,/g," <br />").split(",");
```

Is it possible to get the desired result? (jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/srwwpxh4/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead.

It looks for a non word character first, upper case character followed by a lower case character and insert a line feed before.

```js
var r = /\W+(?=[A-Z][a-z])/g,
    s = 'THIS IS A TITLE This is a paraGraph. This is another paragraph.';

console.log(s.replace(r, '$&\n'));
```

Comment: With `/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/g`, if a word inside the random text is capitalized, a linebreak will be inserted there, too.

Comment: That's perfect. I've never come across a positive lookahead before, so I will do some further ready - cheers!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i inserted a search for a non word character.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes, I see, the point is that OP approach is faulty, not the pattern you suggest.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i see the problem, but op gives the rules.